# Is there a way to use cherrypy's Monitor to perform a single task and then stop?

Tags: multithreading, monitor, cherrypy

I have a web application that requests a report that takes more than 10 minutes to run. Apart from improving that performance, I would for now prefer to set up a thread to run the report and mail it to the user, returning that decision message back to the user immediately.

I have been looking at cherrypy.process.plugins.Monitor, but I'm not clear if it is the correct choice (what to do with the frequency parameter?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monitor is not the correct choice; it's for running the same task repeatedly on a schedule. You're probably better off just calling `threading.Thread(target=run_report).start()`. You can then return `202 Accepted` to the user, along with a URL for the client to watch the status and/or retrieve the newly-created report resource when it's ready.

The one caveat to that is that you might want your new thread to shut down gracefully when the cherrypy.engine stops. Have a look at the various plugins for examples of how to hook into the 'stop' channel on the bus. The other option would be to make your thread daemonic, if you don't care if it terminates abnormally.

Comment: Many thanks, fumanchu. Perhaps I can better employ Monitor to watch the print job (via inspecting the value of a DB entry that is periodically updated while the print job is running) and then shut down the print job thread.

Answer (score 0):

Besides agreeing with fumanchu's answer, I would like to add that the **frequency** parameter is actually the **period** expressed in seconds.`cherrypy.process.plugins.Monitor` (the name is misleading).

Another possible solution could be having a monitor executed periodically, and a set of working computations which can be checked periodically for completion. The code would be something like

```
class Scheduler:

    def __init__ (self):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.mon = Monitor(cherrypy.engine, check_computations, frequency=whatever)
        self.mon.start()
        self.computations = list() # on which we append stuff

    def check_computations (self):
        with self.lock:
            for i in self.computations:
                check(i) # Single check function
```

Caveats:

- The computation time of `check` matters. You don't want to have workload on this perioic routine
- Beware on how you use locks:

  - It is protecting the `computations` list;
  - If you access it (even indirectly) from with `check` your program gets into deadlock. This could be the case if you want to unsubscribe something from the `computations` list.

Comment: Thanks, Dacav, for that thought-out answer. I have put my cherrypy investigations on hold while pursuing web2py and flask. However, the mechanism you proposed is intriguing ...